# Make a worksheet active depending on value in cell from another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following macro which copies the values entered on the "Add Course" worksheet to cells on the "Bloggs, Joe" worksheet. 
How do I change it so it uses the value from C3 in the "Add Course" worksheet instead of the hard coded "Bloggs, Joe"?

```
Sheets("Add Course").Select
Range("C4").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Bloggs, Joe").Select
Range("C7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sheets("Add Course").Select
Range("C4").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets(Sheets("Add Course").Range("C3").Value).Select
Range("C7").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Even though your answer is correct, you should read here why you should avoid using select https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 3):

Learn how to avoid Select and make your code quicker, more efficient and more concise.

```
With WorkSheets("Add Course")
    .Range("C4").Copy WorkSheets(.Range("C3").Value).Range("C7")
End With
```

Comment: Almost as if I'm hardwired to ignore it! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [how to avoid using `Select`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) and try something like this:

```
Worksheets(Worksheets("Add Course").Range("C3").Value).Range("C7").Value = Worksheets("Add Course").Range("C4").Value
```

Comment: You were so rush typing it in you forgot to add the `Range("C7")` at the end of `Worksheets(Worksheets("Add Course").Range("C3").Value)`